# HTTP Request Android - Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, android, http, get

So I have a problem. I have been trying to get an http request to work for quite a while now, and I have made a new thread so that the request never runs on the main thread. I have successfully made it so that the HTTP Request occurs and in the request thread I have made it so it logs the data that it has grabbed from the http request. Now if I ever want to use this jsonObject outside the method it gives me errors. Help?

LogCat:

```
02-23 22:48:08.612    4239-4239/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio, PID: 4239
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONArray.toString()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONArray.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-23 22:48:09.332    4239-4254/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio I/log_tag﹕ [{"Name":"Cabinet","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"40.83990100","Longitude":"14.25185000","pk":19587,"image_id":"2006AJ6728"},{"Name":"Panel","Location":"Medieval and Renaissance, room 8, case WS EXP","Latitude":"48.87287900","Longitude":"4.63710000","pk":11371,"image_id":"2006AP3163"},{"Name":"Wallpaper","Location":"British Galleries, room 122f, case 1","Latitude":"53.47962200","Longitude":"-2.24881000","pk":19492,"image_id":"2006AU6265"},{"Name":"Portrait miniature","Location":"British Galleries, room 58c, case 2","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":9491,"image_id":"2006AH0271"},{"Name":"Caricature","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"53.02513900","Longitude":"-2.18676000","pk":29979,"image_id":"2006AE9142"},{"Name":"Card game","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":26483,"image_id":"2006AU5916"},{"Name":"Tile","Location":"Islamic Middle East, room 42, case WW9","Latitude":"39.76586200","Longitude":"64.42234000","pk":30220,"image_id":"2006AY5617"},{"Name":"Sculpture","Location":"Sculpture, room 22, case 2","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":36026,"image_id":"2006AM7780"},{"Name":"Oil painting","Location":"Prints & Drawings Study Room, room 315, case 24, shelf R","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":6905,"image_id":"2006AU6480"},{"Name":"Snuff bottle","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"36.89445100","Longitude":"104.16564900","pk":10895,"image_id":"2006AU8783"},{"Name":"Snuff bottle","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"36.89445100","Longitude":"104.16564900","pk":10902,"image_id":"2006AU9234"}]
02-23 22:48:09.332    4239-4254/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio I/log_tag﹕ [{"Name":"Cabinet","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"40.83990100","Longitude":"14.25185000","pk":19587,"image_id":"2006AJ6728"},{"Name":"Panel","Location":"Medieval and Renaissance, room 8, case WS EXP","Latitude":"48.87287900","Longitude":"4.63710000","pk":11371,"image_id":"2006AP3163"},{"Name":"Wallpaper","Location":"British Galleries, room 122f, case 1","Latitude":"53.47962200","Longitude":"-2.24881000","pk":19492,"image_id":"2006AU6265"},{"Name":"Portrait miniature","Location":"British Galleries, room 58c, case 2","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":9491,"image_id":"2006AH0271"},{"Name":"Caricature","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"53.02513900","Longitude":"-2.18676000","pk":29979,"image_id":"2006AE9142"},{"Name":"Card game","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":26483,"image_id":"2006AU5916"},{"Name":"Tile","Location":"Islamic Middle East, room 42, case WW9","Latitude":"39.76586200","Longitude":"64.42234000","pk":30220,"image_id":"2006AY5617"},{"Name":"Sculpture","Location":"Sculpture, room 22, case 2","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":36026,"image_id":"2006AM7780"},{"Name":"Oil painting","Location":"Prints & Drawings Study Room, room 315, case 24, shelf R","Latitude":"52.88328900","Longitude":"-1.97685000","pk":6905,"image_id":"2006AU6480"},{"Name":"Snuff bottle","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"36.89445100","Longitude":"104.16564900","pk":10895,"image_id":"2006AU8783"},{"Name":"Snuff bottle","Location":"In Storage","Latitude":"36.89445100","Longitude":"104.16564900","pk":10902,"image_id":"2006AU9234"}]
02-23 22:48:32.712    4239-4239/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4239 SIG: 9
```

Code:

```
package com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio;
//All the imports happen when you auto complete. Often you may have erros when you copy paste things directly because libraries may not get imported
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String [] drinks;
    JSONArray jsonObject;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set the content view to activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JSONArray object = new JSONArray();
        object = getData();
        Log.i("log_tag", jsonObject.toString());

//        System.out.print("success: " + object.toString());


        drinks = new String[3];
        drinks[0] = "hi";
        drinks[1] = "5";
        drinks[2] = "3";
 /**
  * Lists require adapters-Adapters are the place that we store the various data items we want
  to appear in the Lists. This will be handled in an adapter.
  */

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//We will create the array adapter and reference it to our individual List item from the ListView and then to the array we just created- Drinks.
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,drinks);

//We finally will connect the adapter to the List View
        ListView drinkLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Set the drinks array to the adapter below
        drinkLists.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public JSONArray getData(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://stampwatch.herokuapp.com/");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    try {
                        response = client.execute(httpGet);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                        int b;
                        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }

                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
                        Log.i("log_tag", jsonObject.toString());
;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("log_tag", jsonObject.toString());
                    }

            }).start();
            return jsonObject;
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RenéLink Write an answer and I will +1 and accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
 Log.i("log_tag", jsonObject.toString());
```

`NPE` because `jsonObject` is `null` and trying to call `toString()` method for JSONObject using null object.

> But why is the object null if I have made a request with that object?

Because `jsonObject` object is initialized inside `getData();` method in which a Thread is used for getting data from api. means :

```
Log.i("log_tag", jsonObject.toString());
```

line executing just after starting Thread instead of wait until thread is finish.

Comment: But why is the object null if I have made a request with that object?

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack:  see my edit answer probably understand why `jsonObject` is null

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack: Good if use `AsyncTask` instead of Thread for updating UI data after getting response from server

Comment: Accepted answer thanks for the edit, one more thing: how do I execute stuff after the thread is finished? Is there a callback I can use or something? Or do I have to use AsyncTasks, I was told to stay away from them.

Comment: @LucaSpeedStack: `Is there a callback I can use or something?` there is no callbacks but you can create custom callbacks using interfaces, use `AsyncTask` because this class provide onPostExecute method as call back which is called when doInBackground  Thread execution completed